# Pointer receiver and value receiver in Exercise:Image

Tags: go

I am quite new to go, and quite confused about the receiver idea in Go. It is the exercise from A tour of Go.

Question body:

> Remember the picture generator you wrote earlier? Let's write another
>   one, but this time it will return an implementation of image.Image
>   instead of a slice of data.
>
> Define your own Image type, implement the necessary methods, and call
>   pic.ShowImage.
>
> Bounds should return a image.Rectangle, like image.Rect(0, 0, w, h).
>
> ColorModel should return color.RGBAModel.
>
> At should return a color; the value v in the last picture generator
>   corresponds to color.RGBA{v, v, 255, 255} in this one.

Here is my code:

```
package main

import "golang.org/x/tour/pic"
import "image"
import "image/color"


type Image struct{}

func (img *Image) Bounds() image.Rectangle{
    w := 100
    h := 100
    return image.Rect(0,0,w,h)
}

func (img *Image) ColorModel() color.Model{
    return color.RGBAModel
}

func (img *Image) At(x int, y int) color.Color{
    return color.RGBA{uint8(x^y), uint8(y/2), 255,255}
}

func main() {
    m := Image{}
    pic.ShowImage(m)
}
```

And it will report a compile error:

## command-line-arguments ./compile110.go:26: cannot use m (type Image) as type image.Image in argument to pic.ShowImage:    Image does not implement image.Image (At method has pointer receiver)

---

My understanding is that for receivers of methods, it is alright to set them as either pointers or values. However, when I set all the "*Image" to "Image", the errors go away.

Can someone help me with this?

---

The answers provided below are sufficient for the question I raised. However, it seems that the pointer and value receivers thingy can be a bit more complicated.

From Effective Go:

> The rule about pointers vs. values for receivers is that value methods
>   can be invoked on pointers and values, but pointer methods can only be
>   invoked on pointers. This rule arises because pointer methods can
>   modify the receiver; invoking them on a value would cause the method
>   to receive a copy of the value, so any modifications would be
>   discarded. The language therefore disallows this mistake. There is a
>   handy exception, though. When the value is addressable, the language
>   takes care of the common case of invoking a pointer method on a value
>   by inserting the address operator automatically.

Hope this will help some of you as well.

Comment: Why are you even giving these function receivers? You don't use them. I feel like you are trying to make an `interface`.

Comment: it is a requirement of the question. I suspect the pic.ShowImage() is calling these methods for the interface image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use interfaces in Go you need to make sure the instance you are using implements that interface.  In the Go-Tour example problem, `Image` does not satisfy the `image.Image` interface, only `&Image` does.

As such you need to either change your method signatures to take value receivers which will make `Image` work, or pass `&Image` to the `pic.ShowImage` function since the pointer to `Image` does implement the interface.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can go about fixing this.

one way is using

```
func main() {
    m := &Image{}
    pic.ShowImage(m)
}
```

the other way is using a constructor

```
func NewImage() *Image {
    return &Image{}
}

func main() {
    m := NewImage()
    pic.ShowImage(m)
}
```